# Dart/Flutter: Split string before last character

Tags: string, flutter, dart, split

I have a single string made up of numbers of varying lengths, example: "12345"

I would like to break the String before the last character, so that I have ["1234", "5"]

I can do this with substring, but I would like a more simplified way, like using split(), but I don't know how

Below, example using substring:

```
 String numbers = '123456';
 var partOne = numbers.substring(0, numbers.length -1);
 var partTwo = numbers.substring(numbers.length -1, numbers.length);
 print('partOne $partOne - partTwo $partTwo'); // partOne 12345 - part Two 6
```

Comment: You already know how to do it with `substring` which is the most straightforward and most efficient way to do it.  If that's too much trouble, then just make a function (which could be an extension method) to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  const numbers = '123456';
  final re = RegExp('(.*)(.)');
  final match = re.firstMatch(numbers);
  if (match != null) {
    print(match.group(1));
    print(match.group(2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this simpler for you?

```dart
String numbers = '123456';
List<String> parts = [numbers.substring(0, numbers.length - 1), numbers[numbers.length - 1]];
print('partOne ${parts[0]} - partTwo ${parts[1]}'); // partOne 12345 - partTwo 6
```